# Share disk in multiple VMs using vmware vshpere API?

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I am trying to share volume disk between multiple vms, is there any vmware API or any sdk solution to do this? I tried VIJava sdk but there are basic operations as vm creation , deletion and cloning..

thanks in advance...!!

Answer (score 0):

From the API/SDK side, check out the [`ReconfigVM_Task`](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22/fa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc/doc/vim.VirtualMachine.html#reconfigure). It's complex to use, but it lets you reconfigure each volume separately.

In the `VirtualMachineConfigSpec` object, you should provide a `deviceChange` representing the disk you want to add/modify. You will then add the same disk (same vmdk filename in case of a VMDK or same physical device in case of RDM) to another VM.

If you've never used the vSphere SDK then it can be a bit daunting. Post specific follow up questions (with your code) if needed.

Is using PowerCLI out of the question? It has a [`New-HardDisk` cmdlet](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41/html/New-HardDisk.html).